# Add transitions to arrows beneath an equation

Tags: beamer, equations, transition

I am trying to make simple transitions between the terme of a simple equation, I add them `<+-| alert@+>`  to my items like so :

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{I-Vocabulary}
 \begin{Vocabulary}{1-Addition}
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{itemize}
 \begin{gather}
 \mathterm[t1]{   27.32   }   +
 \mathterm[t2]{   1.45  }   =
 \mathterm[t3]{   28.77 }
 \end{gather}
 \end{itemize}
 \item  First Terme \indicate[red]{t1}[out=0,in=-75]
 \item  Second Terme \indicate[blue]{t2}[out=0,in=-90]
 \item  the Sum \indicate{t3}[out=0,in=-90]
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{Vocabulary}
 \end{frame}
```

I get this [image]

Now I need to add transitions, I try this :

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{I-Vocabulary}
 \begin{Vocabulary}{1-Addition}


 \begin{gather}
 \mathterm[t1]{   27.32   }   +
 \mathterm[t2]{   1.45  }   =
 \mathterm[t3]{   28.77 }
 \end{gather}
 \begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]
 \item [<+-| alert@+>]  First Terme \indicate[red]{t1}[out=0,in=-75]
 \item [<+-| alert@+>] Second Terme \indicate[blue]{t2}[out=0,in=-90]
 \item [<+-| alert@+>] the Sum \indicate{t3}[out=0,in=-90]
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{Vocabulary}
 \end{frame}
```

But its messing up the output, it's clear what I want is to display the firt term (whilst the second and third are uncovered) then uncover the second one, then uncover the third one, but I am a not very familiar with this, can someone please help , thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you make this example complete, by adding the necessary packages?  I don't know how you've defined `Vocabulary` and `\mathterm`.

Comment: thanks, I just had to rearrange the code, by there is no problem in the vocabulary I defined it

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal working example that shows us how `\indicate` etc are defined.